# Create node with label using Neo4jClient in f#

Tags: .net, f#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I am trying to create a node and also assign a label to that node. Following the instructions in [Using Neo4j Graph DB With F#](http://sergeytihon.wordpress.com/2013/03/27/using-neo4j-graph-db-with-f/), I managed to create the Person nodes, but I could not create a label Person for the node created. Is my use of the create method wrong? Do I need to pass it as a parameter? Could I use the Cypher create instead of create?

Comment: How do you expect us to know if your use of the method is wrong without posting exactly what you tried?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example uses the old API based way of using 'Create' so you used to do:

```
client.Create person
```

now you can (and should) use the Cypher version:

```
let createPerson person =
    client.Cypher
        .Create("(p:Person {param})")
        .WithParam("param", person)
        .Return<Person>("p")
        .Results
        .Single();

let pA = createPerson { Name = "PersonA"; Twitter = "tA" }
```

And you should be passing in the person as a parameter. Using the Cypher version is the only way to get labels into your db.

Comment: If you are interested - I have updated all of Sergey's post here: http://geekswithblogs.net/cskardon/archive/2013/11/27/using-neo4j-with-f-ndash-cypher-2.0.aspx